# OpenLayers, Get attributions property of a source?

Tags: openlayers

I would like to get the attribution property of a source.

```
 new TileLayer({
  opacity: 0.7,
  source: new WMTS({
    attributions:
      'Tiles © <a href="https://mrdata.usgs.gov/geology/state/"' +
      ' target="_blank">USGS</a>',
    url: 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mapcache/wmts',
    layer: 'sgmc2',
    matrixSet: 'GoogleMapsCompatible',
    format: 'image/png',
    projection: projection,
    tileGrid: new WMTSTileGrid({
      origin: getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
      resolutions: resolutions,
      matrixIds: matrixIds,
    }),
    style: 'default',
    wrapX: true,
  }),
})
```

I would like to somehow get the text in the attributions property. I have tried this:

```
layer.getSource().getAttributions()
```

That gives me some form function but I can't figure out how to get the text after that..
If I look att the response in the debugger it says:

```
function(frameState) {
    return [attributionLike];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I think. If I used it like this:

```
layer.getSource().getAttributions()();
```

I got back an array with the attributions.